# GittyUp - Failed to Create Temporary FIle - Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: git

When I am trying to do any command in a repository like Fetch or Commit, I am receving this message:

Unable to stage - failed to create temporary file '/run/flatpak/doc/...': Permission denied

[Failed to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlFTJ.png)

I have tried a few things, like create this folder: flatpak/doc, but ubuntu doesn't allow me to do that.

I really want to use Gittyup, is there a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had been having a similar problem. My use case scenario is using [Gittyup](https://murmele.github.io/Gittyup/) to work on repositories on a remote computer over SSHFS. As it turns out, programs installed as Flatpaks are [sandboxed](https://docs.flatpak.org/en/latest/sandbox-permissions.html). This means you will need to give it additional permissions to access your local system. I think there are ways to do it by CLI (e.g. `flatpak override <package_name_here> --filesystem=<path_here>`). But knowing this could be an issue for other Flatpak programs, I installed [Flatseal](https://flathub.org/apps/com.github.tchx84.Flatseal) which can easily see and modify the permissions and access given to all of my Flatpak installed programs. In the image below I've given Gittyup access to a mounted remote file system by clicking on the icon of the file with a "+" in it.

[Gittyup Flatseal example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCcfP.png)

I hope this helps and good luck!

[git](/questions/tagged/git)[gittyup](/questions/tagged/gittyup)

Comment: This does not seem to work for the GittyUp problem, also not after creating the directory `/run/flatpak` and `chmod 777`

Answer (score 0):

This was my situation: I have a separate root partition and /home partition.

I installed the latest Debian in a new ext4 root partition, but kept my old /home partition.  I installed GittyUp in Debian through flatpak.

I could not stage with GittyUp to already existing Git repositories in my /home partition (with similar error messages as the original poster).

The following worked though: I could clone the repository again in GittyUp and I could stage to the newly cloned repository.